# How to force the App to react to a registered Action

Tags: android, android-intent, android-manifest, intentfilter

I have two Apps ImplicitIntent_00 and ImplicitIntent_01. in ImplicitIntent_00, in the manifest file, I registered for the action "android.intent.action.VIEW" as shown below in the manifest file.
While, in implicitintent_01, it has the following code:

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

    String url = "http://www.vogella.com";
    Intent i = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW);
    i.setData(Uri.parse(url));
    i.putExtra("extra", "value");
    startActivity(i);
}
```

}

what I want to do is, when I run implicitintent_01, i want implicitintent_00 App to show up in the selection menu as an App that can perform the "android.intent.action.VIEW" action.
But currently when I run the implicitintent_01 App, the implicitintent_00 never show up among the Apps in the selection menu

how to do that correctly.

**Manifest of implicitIntent_00**:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
package="com.example.com.implicitintent_00" >

<application
    android:allowBackup="true"
    android:icon="@mipmap/ic_launcher"
    android:label="@string/app_name"
    android:supportsRtl="true"
    android:theme="@style/AppTheme" >

    <activity android:name=".MainActivity"
        android:label="@string/app_name">
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.VIEW" />
            <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT" />
            <data android:scheme="http"/>
        </intent-filter>
    </activity>

</application>
```

Answer (score 0):

try using this in your implicitintent_00 manifest activity tag

```
<intent-filter> 
    <action android:name="android.intent.action.VIEW" /> 
    <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT" /> 
    <category android:name="android.intent.category.BROWSABLE" />
</intent-filter>
```

Comment: now, when i run implicitintent_01, the webpage starts immediately without allowing me to select the App that should start browsing

Comment: check this link it has a manifest file of a browser this will help you https://github.com/anthonycr/Lightning-Browser/blob/dev/app/src/main/AndroidManifest.xml